# MariaDB log_error variable

Tags: mysql, logging, wamp, mariadb

In WAMPs MySQL my.ini file you can specify the location of the mysql error log file, but if I try setting this variable in the my.ini of MariaDB it will not start. I assume it is not recognizing the variable, which worked fine in WAMP.

How do I set the MySQL error log file when using MariaDB?

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB uses a separate option called `log-basename`

`--log-basename=name` (for example if name is mypc then `mypc.err` will be created as a error log)

Basename for all log files and the .pid file. This sets all log file names at once (in 'datadir') and is normally the only option you need for specifying log files. 
This is especially recommend to be set if you are using replication as it ensures that your log file names are not depending on your host name. Sets names for `--log-bin`, `--log-bin-index`,`--relay-log`, `--relay-log-index`, `--general-log-file`, `--log-slow-query-log-file`, `--log-error-file`, and `--pid-file`.

Comment: But how do I set the location of the log file? e.g. I want it to be S:\mylog.err not in the data folder.

Comment: You can try `log-error=Error log file path` all options are listed here https://kb.askmonty.org/en/mysqld-options-full-list/